# Trying to create a 'FPL' style results table

Tags: excel-formula, office365

I want to be able to add results into a sheet from my football league and have that automatically add up things like, Games Played, Won, Lost, Drawn, Goals For, Against, Diff and finally, points.

My first hurdle is Games Won.

I want to look at Column B on Sheet 1 and see if it matches the team name, say Team A.

If it does AND the result in column C is greater than that of column D, then I want to add a one to the games won tab. I also want to do this is column E matches the team name and therefore column D is greater than C.

I can share a copy of my sheet if that is easier to see what I am proposing here, as there may be a better approach entirely.

I am doing this in the Web Based Office 365 Excel.

I have tried all forms of =(SUM(IF(AND statments, but I can only get it to work against individual rows, as opposed to a whole table of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by doing this on a different sheet

`=SUM(IF(AND('Scores and Scorers'!$C2>'Scores and Scorers'!$D2,'Scores and Scorers'!$B2=INDIRECT($N$1)),1,0))`

So if C2 on the scores sheet is bigger than D2 AND B2 matches the name of the team in M1 (N1 simply says M1, and M1 says the team name), then it will put a 1.

I then repeated this 50 times (25 games, so 25 times with B2 matching the team name and 25 times with E2 matching incase the team name is entered on the other side of the score) and then summed the results at the top.